# Can a Smart Contract receive and send E-Mails?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

As the title states, I would like to know whether one could create a smart contract on Ethereum that is able to send and receive E-Mails.

Comment: Sure, it can send emails on the Ethereum blockchain (i.e., the data will be on the Ethereum blockchain, and you'll need to implement a client app which will make this data accessible for the users of your email-service).

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for your answer. Either I don't understand it correctly, or I need another solution. Let us move away from sending and get to receiving first. My goal is that a smart contract can receive emails from any external client without the need for some sort of (web3-?)middleware to get the data to the contract. Exemplary use case: With my Outlook client I send an email to inbox@mycontract.io and the data is sent directly to the contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are perceiving emails as data transmitted over classical protocols stmp, pop3,etc
the answer is No it's impossible. As you might know, the smart contract runs in an isolated environment (VM) it has no connection with external networks.

So a smart contract can't connect to an stmp server and send an email to x@provider.com

A contract can receive "transactions" which can play the role of emails !!

Comment: I think I now understand- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could however write some code with the logic to upon receiving text from email, it sends the text to the blockchain via an rpc on the relevant api.